# from .mat to text file respecting format

Tags: matlab, text, mat

I would like to export a column located in a .mat file to a text file. (I am attaching the picture of the mat file).
I have tried:

```
file=load('./file_scan.mat')
mjd=[file.scan.mjd];
save ('./station/mjd.txt','mjd','-ascii')
```

but it puts the data in many columns and I would like to have it in a column like in the mat file.

On the other hand, I know which is the routine that creates the mat file. And the same instruction works fine when I write directly on that routine. But, I want to export the data from the mat file.

Could anybody help me on that?
Thanks in advance,
Eugenia

[image: .mat file]

[image: textfile wrong output]

Comment: Just transpose `mjd`. `mjd = [file.scan.mjd].';`

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking about that after I sent the message. But I didn't understand why the command works fine in the routine and does not work with .mat. Maybe the format of the file is not the same way that I suppose. Thanks!